# Extract from zip file to a list

Tags: python, list, zip

I'm trying to extract a set of photos from a zip file using python
and then saving those pictures to an image list to do some work on each.

I tried a lot, but nothing was useful to me.

Comment: What do you mean by saving them to a image list? the path to the file, or the uncompressed binary of it? Do you have some sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import zipfile

path = 'path_to_zip.zip'
input_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
l = [input_zip.read(name) for name in input_zip.namelist()]
```

To Display one of the images you can do:

```py
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(l[0]))
plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: I'm trying to save the actual images not the name of the images in the file, can you help me with that?

Comment: This only uses the name to locate the files inside the zipfile. Its going to keep the images in memory, and not actually save them to disk. Do you want them to be saved to disk?

Comment: no, I'm trying to do some coding on the images, like face detection and so, but i need to read from zipfile first

Comment: Then the code I posted above does what you want. It returns a list containing the binary data of each image inside the zipfile

Comment: I saw the binary data, but have no idea how to display them as image :\

Comment: Depends on the format of the file. Usually something like `imshow` can do the trick, but also depends on how you are running python.

Comment: I added this line: 
imgfile = Image.open(zipfile.open(zf.namelist()[1]))

Comment: That works too. I updated my answer with an alternative. Glad it worked